# How to test an iterator function with pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a function that provides a batch iterator over an iterable using a batch size argument:

```py
def batch_iterator(iterable: Iterable[Row], batch_size: int) -> Iterator:
    """
    Slices off a batch of values from an iterable, and returns it as an iterator.
    """
    return iter(lambda: list(itertools.islice(iterable, batch_size)), [])
```

I want to test the function with pytest. Here is what I've tried and the error:

```py
def test_batch_iterator():

    words_tuple = ('jimi', 'bertrand', 'alain', 'buck', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'oak', 'maple', 'python')
    result = batch_iterator(3, words_tuple)
    assert result == iter(words_tuple[:2])

#----------------------------------------------------------

the pytest result at the console:
...
Expected :<tuple_iterator object at 0x00000216F2F23130>
Actual   :<callable_iterator object at 0x00000216F2F23070>
<Click to see difference>

def test_batch_iterator():
    
        words_tuple = ('jimi', 'bertrand', 'alain', 'buck', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'oak', 'maple', 'python')
        result = batch_iterator(3, words_tuple)
>       assert result == iter(words_tuple[:2])
E       assert <callable_iterator object at 0x00000216F2F23070> == <tuple_iterator object at 0x00000216F2F23130>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`batch_iterator(words_tuple, 3)` returns an iterator with `['jimi', 'bertrand', 'alain']`. To get the list from it you can use `next`. You also need to switch the parameters when invoking `batch_iterator()` and change `words_tuple` to a list, or cast it in the assertion

```
words_tuple = ['jimi', 'bertrand', 'alain', 'buck', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'oak', 'maple', 'python']
result = batch_iterator(words_tuple, 3)
assert next(result) == words_tuple[:3]
```

Update

Currently `batch_iterator` creates an `iterator` with only the first 3 values. If you want all the entries in `words_tuple` you can use something like

```
def batch_iterator(iterable: Iterable[Row], batch_size: int) -> Iterator:
    """
    Slices off a batch of values from an iterable, and returns it as an iterator.
    """
    return iter(iterable[i:i+batch_size] for i in range(0, len(iterable), batch_size))

words_tuple = ('jimi', 'bertrand', 'alain', 'buck', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'oak', 'maple', 'python')
result = batch_iterator(words_tuple, 3)
assert next(result) == words_tuple[:3]
```

Comment: Thanks @Guy this got me over the hump, and taught me a little about iterators/iterables. On that point though I still don't get why I can't check that a second call to `next()` on the result iterator doesn't work as expected, i.e. this line doesn't work as expected after the first assertion using next():
```
assert next(result) == list(words_tuple[3:6])
``` (the second next call still returns the first three elements, rather than the expected second three)